# Why use a generator object in this particular case?

Tags: python, list, web-crawler, generator

I was looking at a bit of code I downloaded from the internet. It's for a basic webcrawler. I came across the following `for` loop:

```
for link in (links.pop(0) for _ in xrange(len(links))):
    ...
```

Now, I feel the following code will also work:

```
for link in links:
    ....
links=[]
```

Researching, I found out that the first instance clears `links` and also generates a `generator object (genexpr)`. `links` is never used in the `for` loop, so its decreasing length has nothing to do with the code.

Is there any particular reason for using the xrange, and popping the elements each time? I.e. Is there any advantage to using a generator object over calling elements of the standard list? Additionally, in what cases would a generator be useful; why?

Comment: Maybe the code inside the `for` loop (elided in your question) depends on the fact that `len(links)` decreases with each iteration?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi len(links) will only be called once

Comment: @robert, I was referring to code inside the loop, which we do not see, not to the initial invocation of `len(links)` in the call to `xrange()`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi ah sorry you're right

Comment: No. Like I mentioned, `links` is never used inside the loop. Not even its length.

Comment: and in other threads? If still no, the author might have taken the code snippet from somewhere else where it was needed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's hard to see any justification for the code you quoted.

The only thing I can think of is that the objects in `links` might be large, or otherwise associated with scarce resources, and so it might be important to free them as soon as possible (rather than waiting until the end of the loop to free them all). But (a) if so, it would be better to process each link as you created it (perhaps using a generator to organize the code), instead of building up the whole list of links before starting to process it; and (b) even if you had no choice but to build up the whole list before processing it, it would be cheaper to clear each list entry than to pop the list:

```
for i, link in enumerate(links):
    links[i] = None
    ...
```

(Popping the first element off a list with *n* items takes O(*n*), although in practice it will be fairly fast since it's implemented using `memmove`.)

Even if you absolutely insisted on repeatedly popping a list as you iterated across it, it would be better to write the loop like this:

```
while links:
    link = links.pop(0)
    ...
```

Comment: It's shorter, it's clearer because there are fewer operations, and it avoids constructing unnecessary `xrange` and generator objects. But everyone has their own taste, so it wouldn't be wrong to use the generator version.

Comment: In a similiar case, I even use a `ListPart` case which supports iteration as well as indexing for taking parts off a list. If comments would allow for linebreaks, I would put it here (so probably it is good that it is not possible); it can be used like `a = ListPart([1, 2, 3, 4]); b = a[2:4]; c=list(a); print a, b, c`and it prints `myiter.ListPart([]) [3, 4] [1, 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of generators is to avoid building large collections of *intermediate* objects that won't serve any external use.

If all the code is doing is building the set of links on a page, the second code snippet is fine. But perhaps what might be desired is the set of root websites names (eg google.com rather than google.com/q=some_search_term....). If this is the case, you'd then take the list of links and then go through the full list, stripping out just the first part.

It's for this second stripping portion where you'd gain more by using a generator. Rather than having needlessly built a list of links which takes memory and time to build, you can now pass through each link one-by-one, getting the website name without a big intermediary list of all links.

Comment: But even in the second case, assuming we're stripping the links, we're eventually working with one link at a time. All the operations in the `for` loop deal with `link`, not `links`. Python won't be generating a new list no matter how much `link` is changed.

Comment: @shashwat Yes, but the fewer intermediary objects you make, the better the performance will be. Speed will also be returned by forming a generator and at the last moment calling list() on the generator. Lots of appends to a list will be slower.

Comment: @shashwat I don't see the point in using xrange(len(...)) like that though